# Where should I use "bitte" in imperative sentences?

Tags: word-order, imperative

I've read that it's better to place *bitte* in the middle of the sentence, but I don't know where.

For example to say the imperative form of "bitte das Fenster zumachen", which one is correct?

"Mach *bitte* das Fenster zu" or "Mach das Fenster *bitte* zu" ?

also here:

"Füll *bitte* das Formular aus" or "Füll das Formular *bitte* aus" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (1) Bitte mach das Fenster zu! / Bitte füll das Formular aus!
>
> (2) Mach bitte das Fenster zu! / Füll bitte das Formular aus!
>
> (3) Mach das Fenster bitte zu! / Füll das Formular bitte aus!

All are correct and even this is correct:

> (4) Mach das Fenster zu, bitte! / Füll das Formular aus, bitte!

Mostly used are (2) and (3), then (1).

All versions are polite, but the politer the closer the *»bitte«* is located towards the beginning of the sentence, since the *»bitte«* is transporting the message that the sentence is polite.

However, the most polite way is to drop the imperative and use a question.

> Könntest/Würdest du bitte das Fenster zumachen?

Comment: Which version is better? And why?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ich finde, die Position des "bitte" macht keinen Unterschied in der Höflichkeit, im Gegensatz zum Tonfall.

Comment: @Robert: Sätze mit _»bitte«_ sind im Ton meist gut verträglich. Ein frühes _»bitte«_ ist dadurch höflicher, dass man schneller merkt, dass ein höflicher Satz formuliert wird. Die Zeitspanne, in der der Satz nach Befehl klingt, ist kürzer.